# Should I use a drag-and-drop or self-program my user interface?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

As a CS student trying to make my first application is it better to program the user interface myself or should I use the drag and drop option of JFrame?

Drag and drop seems quicker, but I find it hard to understand instructions generated. So the dilemma is do it myself or drag and drop and  try to understand afterwards.

Comment: Desktop application!

Comment: no matter which tool you choose to create the ui - you have to learn and understand what you are doing :) Which implies working carefully through appropriate tutorial/s, starting f.i. with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Answer (score 2):

Write the code yourself.

Drag-and-drop GUI builders generate poor code that is quite hard to maintain.  That may or may not matter for a school project, but if you plan to write any programs for any other purpose, you’ll want to be able to fix them and update them.

Drag-and-drop builders usually generate GUI elements with hard-coded sizes and positions, which is something GUIs must avoid—a button will need a different pixel size to accommondate its text in Windows than it needs on a Mac, and the default preferred size already accounts for that.

Furthermore, laying out a GUI is about more than how it looks.  It’s also about how the GUI behaves.  When the user resizes the window, which GUI elements in the window should resize with it?  Which ones should stick to the edges, and which edges should they stick to?  While you *can* specify all of this in a drag-and-drop GUI builder, the builder makes it very easy to ignore all of it.  You will have a GUI that looks right at a glance, but it may not behave right.

Finally, if you plan to do GUI development for any jobs, you will need to know how to write the code.  So learning to do it now is doing yourself a favor.

Writing the code yourself will likely require perusing [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/module-summary.html) a lot.  No one is expected to memorize it, of course, but as you keep going back to it for information about various GUI elements, you will probably learn things about them that you might not have known if you had relied on a drag-and-drop builder.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can definitely use the drag and drop GUI.

Netbeans has support for automatic resizing of components which allows really nice and fast development.
But avoid all the "code" parts of netbeans, like code when you click on buttons etc. Those it's better to code yourself so you understand what happens.

Later, you can of course learn to program editors yourself, but usually, most companies use different GUI frameworks anyway (or don't use desktop at all), and the GUI parts are the simple part of programming.

Of course, it doesn't hurn to know how to create simple JFrame / JDialog and a few buttons programmatically, especially for stuff like dynamic content (ie. creating elements when program is running)

Comment: So for a school project that's due in a month and a half , you will recommend the drag and drop?

Comment: I would say it kinda depends on the assignment., but  it will allow you to get the boring parts done quickly so you can concentrate on the actual assignment, since i'm guessing is that your project involves doing some sort of logic that will be the difficult / bigger part of it.

Comment: Yes there's another big part to take care of. Thank you for your help!